# Best way to get data from 2 different databases (MSSQL Server and MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance

I have a website that uses 2 different DMS (MSSQL Server and MySQL). There is a table name `product` in both databases, these 2 tables have the same product ID.

- In MSSQL Server: I stored price, quantity.
- In MySQL: I stored name, size,...

Now, every time I query products, I would do like this:
- Connect to MySQL -> query products by a loop -> inside every loop, I will connect to MSSQL Server to get other data of this product.

I know this is totally a bad way, so I'm finding a new way to get what I want since I think my website is slower because of that kind of query.

Can you help me by writing pseudo-code or explanation, thank you.

Comment: If you where using MariaDB you could use a [connect engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect/) to the MSSQL database using odbc/jdbc. With your existing form I'd retrieve a full list of products and do one query to the MSSQL server. Do you have a plan to rationalize to a single DB product, or move jobs to avoid the employer/client that insists on this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You are right! Having your website data in 2 different database technologies is not optimal.

Until you fix that, one workaround could be (assuming we are not talking millions of records):

- User selects product A or Product category X on the website.
- Get all data for product A or products of category X from SQL Server and store it in memory (for eg. in a c# dataset or python data frame)
- Get all data for product A or products of category X from MySQL and store it in memory (for eg. in a c# dataset or python data frame)
- Join the 2 in memory objects based on Product Id
- Use this combined dataset for display your website
- If required, Update (commit) data to the databases at the end of the session (will need to consider how to deal with dirty read scenarios)